# Does AWS Textract support Hindi text in a png file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract

I need to do OCR on images that contain text in Hindi, Marathi, Malayalam, etc languages. I am using AWS Textract API in the python script, but OCR on Scanned Hindi text Document gives a response with the incorrect English like words.

Does AWS Textract support the Hindi language?

Please guide me on this.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the documents from AWS, which enlist supported languages by Amazon Textract;

- [Amazon Textract supports handwriting and five new languages](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/amazon-textract-supports-handwriting-and-five-new-langauges/)
- [Hard Limits in Amazon Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/limits.html)
- [Amazon Textract FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/faqs/)

Moreover, you can think in direction of using Amazon Comprehend, please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/supported-languages.html) document for more information about supported languages by Amazon Comprehend.

Comment: Thank you amitd for your valuable response. Really Helpful.